# AngularJS: Removing Aria attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS datepicker plugin. It is adding `aria-required=false` attribute dynamically to datepicker `md-content`. I want to remove that attribute. As it is coming dynamically through Angular, I cannot do it through HTML, so I want JS code to remove that.

I've tried couple of approaches, but none of them seem to work. Just to mention one approach, which didn't work:

```
$('.datepicker-class').removeAttr('aria-required');
```

There are no console errors, but still it didn't remove the attribute.

Any solution to remove this attribute through JS?

Comment: Why do you want to remove that attribute? Do you know what it is used for?

Comment: The QA has raised error `aria-required` should only be used on HTML form elements. And as `md-custom-datepicker` is not valid input field, it should not have aria-required attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
angular.element('.datepicker-class').removeAttr('aria-required')
})
```

JQuery doesn't always play well with angular as they exists within different execution contexts, but you can use the angular.element function which will use JQlite (enough for what you're doing) or JQuery if you're using that.